# How would I make a script that takes my clipboard and uses it as a variable in a web link

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell, script, clipboard

I have a task at work where I have to go to an Excel sheet and copy the a bunch of asset IDs from a column 1 by 1 and input that in to an intranet site to get the details of the asset.

The web link for the intranet site is laid out like so:

http.://inventory.company.com/assets/*asset ID*

The asset ID bit is the only part that changes between assets, the rest of that address is the same.

What I want to do is a make a script that will copy the contents of my clip board, the asset IDs, and input them in to that link 1 by 1, opening tabs in a web browser as it does so.

I honestly have no idea where to start. I know Power Shell has the get-clipboard cmdlet and that it can get websites with start-process but past that I'm clueless.

Comment: So you need to open a whole bunch of links at once? If this is a one-off thing, I would suggest a different approach - create another column that concatenates the static portion of the link and the asset ID, then just copy/paste all those into a tool such as [this](https://www.websiteplanet.com/webtools/multiple-url/). 

If you want to go the scripting route, check out [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), you may find it easier than Powershell.

Comment: Its a daily task that if we could automate would save us alot of hassle.
Id like to get it done using PS just so my colleagues can use it without downloading extra stuff, though I will give AutoHotkey a look.

Comment: If your asset IDs are below each other then it would be trival to write something which you can copy the column, paste into a window and then it automatically opens your browser to the correct URLs. Would that work?

Comment: @Thomas Understood. You can very easily compile AHK scripts to standalone executables. I'm sure PS can do it just as well - I personally am more comfortable in AHK, so just putting it out there as an option.

Comment: If by *Xl sheet* you mean *Excel* sheet, I'd suggest to type that out. As it is now, I read *xi* sheet.

Comment: why not just use the `=Hyperlink()` formula in excel, then the person would just open excel and click on those links...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a really simple solution which takes a clipboard of asset IDs (one per line, copied out of excel) and opens a Google Chrome window for each one. Best of all, you don't need to install other software to use it - which may be prevented by company policy.

Save the following as `asset-launcher.bat`:

```
@echo off
echo Paste assets into this window, one per line. Close the window when done.
:start
set /p assetid=
"c:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "http://inventory.company.com/assets/%assetid%"
goto start
```

To use:

1. Launch the batch file by double clicking on it
2. Copy the column of asset IDs you want to use
3. Click on the DOS window to activate it and then right-click to paste the contents
4. Chrome will launch tabs for each of the URLs
5. When you're done, click on the X to close the DOS window.

Comment: Thank you Richard this works perfectly.
Could you explain how exactly it works?

Comment: @Thomas Not a problem. The script reads each line that you enter into a variable called `assetid` and then simply launches Chrome with the URL along with this variable appended to the end. If you’d rather use a different browser or a different URL then it should be pretty each to understand what you need to change.

Answer (score 0):

OK, you really are not asking a single question, it is a project:

1. How to read Excel from Powershell
2. How to select data from Excel
3. Export a list from a specific column
4. Pass the list to PowerShell code to execute a web target with default browser.

> Goto go to an Xl sheet and copy the a bunch of asset IDs from a column
> 1 by 1 and input that in to an intranet site to get the details of the
> asset.
>
> The web link for the intranet site is layed out like so:
>
> http.://inventory.company.com/assets/asset ID
>
> The asset ID bit is the only part that changes between assets, the
> rest of that address is the same.

Then you just need a code line with that line and only pull the 'asset ID' from Excel and loop to open the URL.

> What I want to do is a make a script that will copy the contents of my
> clip board, the asset ids, and input them in to that link 1 by 1,
> opening tabs in a web browser as it does so.

No real need to do this. If you know the column and rows, you can use PowerShell to talk to the XL COM to get data from Excel real-time, then fire `Invoke-Item` cmdlet to execute each, one at a time.

So, in the end, it's just using Powershell to read the Excel workbook, and pull the list of 'Asset ID' and on your code, pass that is as an array to the URL using the cmdlet mentioned.

See [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell%20read%20excel) or the [web](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell%20read%20excel%20data%27&t=h_&ia=web) on how to use PowerShell to read Excel files and pull data from it.